# Popup shrinking when selecting any dropdown

Tags: popup, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have developed a popup using Oracle ADF and am now facing an issue with this pop-up screen on deployment environment. This popup is created as on click of Sidebar Navigation which calls a bounded task flow which is launched in a popup window.

The pop-up consists of fields both drop-downs and text boxes and is shrinking to a very small size whenever any drop-down is clicked. I have looked up in on the web for this issue but found only one possible solution that "modal" property of `af:dialog` of `af:popup` must be true. But this did not resolve my issue as this property was set to true only.

Any pointers in this regard will be highly helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify, You are just making a taskflow open as popup and not using af:popup and af:dialog in your code?

Comment: Or, you are using the taskflow as a region inside af:popup?

Comment: Yes the taskflow opens as a popup and I am not using and `af:popup` or `af:dialog` as the internal framework takes care of it. But i made sure to check **modal** property is set to **true**.

Comment: The popup window takes its size from the components within it.The problem could be with your databound popup components. I think, when you select a drop down value the page and its bindings get refreshed and cause the issue. Try using just some components with static properties in your popup and see if the popup still shrinks on drop down selection.

Comment: I do not think this is the issue as we are not facing this issue in our development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue with the help of my teammate.

We were using **Conditional activation of taskflow** using an EL expression and which was in requestScope and hence any click on the dropdown was trying to postback to the server and the EL was evaluated every time, but as we had `TaskFlowPageDef active property` defined with a **request scope** variable, it was not available for the next request. Hence the taskflow was shrinking.

Changed the scope to `viewScope` and now its perfectly working fine.

**For more details:** refer to this [blog](http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/07/what-you-may-need-to-know-about.html)